# Reading ConnectionStrings in local.settings.json using GetEnvironmentVariable in Azure

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-functions

In Azure function **v1**, am trying to read the connection string present in `local.settings.json` using `GetEnvironmentVariable` static method

Here is my `local.settings.json` file

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "OnPremisesConnection": "Server=test;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  }
}
```

using the following code am reading the connection string

```
string variableName = "OnPremisesConnection";
var res = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:{variableName}")
```

but am getting `NULL` as result. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't using the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[variableName]` option? I'm not sure if Environment variables should/will work locally.

Comment: @Jan_V - It is only supported in `v1`, am advised to use `GetEnvironmentVariable` for better support in future

Comment: @Pரதீப் Big sorry that I made a mistake, if you are still in v1, `GetEnvironmentVariable` can't get ConnectStrings as they are not imported into environment, only Values are available. I will update my answer in your last question.

Comment: @JerryLiu Can you please provide your answer to this post as well or link to the 'last question' that you are referring to, in your comment. This would help other readers. Thanks.

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT Sorry about the missing, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781298/read-custom-settings-from-local-settings-json-in-azure-functions/51784441) it is.

Comment: @JerryLiu Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can try the next:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
 
 string connectionStr = config["ConnectionStrings:OnPremisesConnection"]
```