# Azure Functions - configuration settings returns null when I try to debug locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, configurationmanager

I have the following code:

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionValidateDriverRecord")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssetContext"].ConnectionString;
        string mail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailForErrors"];
```

and local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AssetContext": "data source=server;initial catalog=3md_vistracks_sync;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "EmailForErrors": "brauncomm@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

`connString` has value, but `mail` is null. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In local.settings.json, you should use `Values` instead of `AppSettings`. The file schema is required for Azure function local development.

You probably are using v1 functions, feel free to use ConfigurationManager as you have found it's valid for connectionString. v2 doesn't support ConfigurationManager and you can refer to environment variables, See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781298/read-custom-settings-from-local-settings-json-in-azure-functions/51784441#51784441) for more details about reading local and Azure settings.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions use environment variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp

I'm not sure if there's actual code out there using ConfigurationManager, but that doesn't work for Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have got exactly same issue couple of days back and solved it using IConfigurationBuilder. Here is the code snippet.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        var cstr = config.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString");
        var appSettings = config.GetSection("AppSettings")["EmailForErrors"];

        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For timer triggers, you cannot use Executioncontext. By using below code, you can get the values from Json file.

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

var clientId = config["ClientId"];
```

Comment: does that work when you deploy it? and would it work with NoAutomaticTrigger types?

Comment: Yes, it does. Remember to configure the Application Settings when you deploy Function. So that the values that are defined in the local.setting.json also exists in the remote. If you are deploying it from VS, it gives you option to set the remote application settings or you can do it directly in the Azure portal.