# Azure Function - The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-functions

I developed a Azure Function in Visual Studio and it works when published in Azure (since a year ago).

Now I made a template from that Azure Function, in Visual Studio, and I changed some details, but it's mainly the same. When I test it locally, it works fine.

But when I publish it in Azure and try to test it, I get this error:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized
```

I usually write the Connection String in the Application Settings (and it works well for the older Azure functions).

Here is how the function gets the value of the Connection String:

```
var repo = new GranularRepository(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BoConnectionString"]);
```

I also tried:

```
var repo = new AvgDeliveryTime_GranularRepository(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BodbConnectionString"));
```

Comment: Do you see the value for this setting when browse to the app in the portal?

Comment: Check this thread and comment from johnwc on June25. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/717

Comment: Which version of the Functions runtime are you experiencing this issue in, v1 or v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new Azure Function project.

So my conclusion is that making a *template* from another Azure Function and using that as the new project, in Visual Studio, is creating issues.

Answer (score 7):

According to your description, I could not distinguish your function runtime.

For v1:

You could use both `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to get your connection string in Azure.

```
var a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BoConnectionString"];
var b = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BoConnectionString");
```

For v2:

You could use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` and `ConfigurationBuilder` to get it. Add `ExecutionContext` parameter, which is used to locate function app directory.

```
var a= System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BoConnectionString");
/////////////
public static void Run(...,ExecutionContext context)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    // Get Connection strings
    var connParameter= "MySqlAzureConnection";
    string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString($"{connParameter}");
}
```

Both of v1 and v2 you set the connection string in application settings.
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781298/read-custom-settings-from-local-settings-json-in-azure-functions/51784441#51784441).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you prefix your connection string correctly -

- SQL Server connection strings: Prefixed with SQLCONNSTR_
- MySQL connection strings: Prefixed with MYSQLCONNSTR_
- SQL Database (Azure SQL) connection strings: Prefixed with SQLAZURECONNSTR_
- Custom strings: Prefixed with CUSTOMCONNSTR_

eg:
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCONNSTR_MyConnectionString")`