# Azure: Function host is not running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have a Function App in azure and when I hit the URL of the function app it says "Function host is not running." I have checked the log also in the app insights or in the Azure portal's function app service, it shows the following error message in the function app.

Note: My pipeline's Build & Releases got succeeded, so I am not sure where to check and what is the solution for this. I tried with a new function app but still no luck.

[image]

My Startup.cs file to understand How I have referred the config values,

```
 public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        //var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:DBConnection");

        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var appSettingsSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        RuntimeConfig.appsettings = appSettings;

        var ConnectionString = RuntimeConfig.appsettings.AppDBConnection;
        ///builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShardingDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        //builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();


    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"{context.EnvironmentName}.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
```

I am taking the config values as IConfiguration, it works for my local but don't know how to do the same in the server.

Comment: Do you use something with the name "EIA"?

Comment: are you missing some app settings ?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Yes, How do you know that?

Comment: @Thomas I think yes but I don't know how to add that

Comment: @MdAslam That's in the error message. "EIA: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". so, this EAI needs some configuration (code or app settings). I guess this configuration is wrong or missing

Comment: @MarkusMeyer ahh yeah but how to add my local.settings.json file to the kudu path? I have added it but when I run it again then the build files are getting vanished so I don't know how to make it available in the release bin folder in the azure function app server.. Can you please help me?

Comment: local settings will not be deployed. You have to configure it in the app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings

Comment: you can check this link to configure app settings for azure function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings

Answer (score 1):

while deploying your **Function app** it neither upload **local.settings.json** to Azure or nor makes modification on Application Settings based on **local.settings.json** file.

The **Key-value** pair related to **`EIA`** present in `local.settings.json`, add the same key-value pair in Azure Function App Configuration > Application Settings in the Portal.

For that we have to manually update the **App Settings in portal** or if you are using **Visual studio**, we can update using **VS publish panel**.

#### Add Application Settings using Portal

- Azure Portal -> Your Azure Function -> Configuration Panel -> Application Settings/Connection Strings (Add your custom configuration)
  [image]

#### Add Application Settings using Visual Studio Publish panel

- While publishing your azure function Add your Application settings.
- In a hosting panel right corner click (**`...`**).
- Add your app Settings in Manage Azure App Service Settings.
  [image]
- Add your settings like below
  [image]

Comment: Actually my json values are very simple and that does not contain any key name EIA, I have like => 
  "AppSettings": {
    "AppDBConnection": "xyz db connection string;",
    
  }

Comment: I tried with adding these json config values  in the configurations as well but the error remain same.

Comment: if you are adding the DB connection settings try to add in a connection strings under the Application Settings panel. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/8Y9La4d.png)

Comment: I have edited my questions with statup.cs file code so please check and let me know what would be the solution, I understood the problem as you mentioned but it does not work even after created the configurations-application settings as well

Comment: you can use **`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ConnectionStrings:{<Your connection string name >}")`** to get the exact connection string value.

Comment: So I should not use the IConfiguration then ?

Comment: You can use any one of approach. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784441/15997690). And also you can use Iconfiguration . Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959258/how-to-add-an-appsettings-json-file-to-my-azure-function-3-0-configuration)